# .HasRequired Unable to work in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've been searching around for an answer, and unable to find a suitable one that works. I have two models with a 1:* relationship to start with:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class Blog 
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public string BloggerName { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
    } 
}

namespace test.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my `ApplicationDbContext` is:

```
namespace test.Models
{
     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
             base.OnModelCreating(builder);
             base.OnModelCreating(builder);
             builder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(p => p.Blog);
         }
     }
 }
```

However, I get the error of:

> CS1061: 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasRequiered' and no extension method 'HasRequiered' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm new to this so have been following various tutorials but all recommended use of it this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. All I want to do is ensure the `<post>` is always part of a blog. `HasRequiered` always appears in red with this error though.

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? It's `HasRequired`, not `HasRequiered`

Comment: Please add the using directives from the top of your context class.

Comment: Also try using namespace: using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

Comment: Problem I'm having is all of it works if I comment out certain "usings". I need "using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
//using Microsoft.Data.Entity;" With the // commented out one allowing everything in the protected override function to work, but not the OnModelCreating. Maybe I should load a new file inside the protected override?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
     builder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(p => p.Blog);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works in part with certain usings commented out as seen in the comment section above. Probably an error on my behalf of what I'm "using" as this answer helped cleared it up a lot. Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you add what "usings" you are using for this please? I can't find any that recognise .Conventions and allow .HasRequiered to work.